# Reading HTML tag attribute names containing @ in R using xml2 package

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

I am trying to read a HTML document in R containing some vue.js script. This document contains tags with attributes containing @ symbol.

When I read the document using read_html in R the attributes containing @ symbol are not parsed correctly.

```
read_html("<html><title @click='method'>Hi</title></html>")
```

```
{xml_document}
<html>
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<title>Hi</title>\n</head>
```

The whole @click attribute is missing from the title tag. Can someone please let me know how to read tag attributes containing @ character?

Another example with inconsistent behaviour:

```
read_html("<html><title @click='$vuetify.goTo(0, goToOptions)' id='scrollBtn' style='display:none;' v-scroll='scrollfun'>Hi</title></html>")
```

```
{xml_document}
<html>
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<title gotooptions id="scrollBtn" style="display:none;" v-scroll="scrollfun">Hi</title>\n</head>
```

Comment: I think the note in the `?read_html` page is relevant: "HTML is normalized to valid XML" and [XML has rules about names](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name) such that they need to start with a letter. So I don't think you'll be able to use `xml2` here. I'm not aware of any R package that does true HTML (not just XML-like) parsing.

Comment: Thank You @MrFlick for your input. I guess I am stuck then. On an unrelated note, Do you happen to know of any other true HTML parser in Python or Julia, I could try to learn to use packages from one of those languages to interface with R to perform better html parsing.

Comment: Maybe check here for something you can work with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers. I don't have any experience with alternative parsers.